# Wordpress Automatic Login after Registration in Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, authentication, hook, registration

I have a plugin for registration process in wordpress. There was no password field but I created a password field and inserted the password instead of sending random password in emails. It is using wp_create_user function to create the user.

Now, I am trying to make the automatic login after registration but failed in it.

I tried the following function but failed in it. Please someone help.

```
wp_set_current_user($user_id); // set the current wp user
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id); // start the cookie for the current registered user
wp_redirect(home_url());
```

Here is the process that I have been using, it's not complete but how I think that it must work.

```
$status = wp_create_user($username, $user_pass, $email);
$user_data = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $users_table where user_login='$username' ");
$user_id = isset($user_data) ? $user_data->ID : 0;

if (is_wp_error($status)) {
$errors[] = language_code('USER_NAME_ALREADY_EXIST_PLEASE_TRY_ANOTHER_ONE');
} else { 
wp_set_current_user($user_id); 
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id); 
wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
}
```

Comment: can you share you codes, its hard to detect hows you tried.

Comment: I have shared some code above. It's not complete but how I've been doing is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code into your theme functions.php file,It will work

```
function auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_new_user' );
```

Comment: I tried it before as well but it is not working for me.

Comment: are you using any plugin for registration?

Comment: Yes, I have been using a plugin for registration.

Comment: which plugin have you used?